# How to go about abstracting away different JSON library implementations

Tags: c#, .net, json

For my **.NET/C#** project, I need to use a **JSON** library but I should be dependent on a specific implementation. I know that there are plenty of **JSON** **c#** libraries out there like [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), [FastJson](http://fastjson.codeplex.com/), Simple **Json** ([simplejson.codeplex.com](http://simplejson.codeplex.com)), etc. Now how should I abstract away different implementations so that I will be able to switch libraries in a future time. I have no control on other libraries but I have full control on my project. Looking for your opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your needs you can create a single entry point to whatever library you wish to use.

```
public static class Json
{
    public static string Serialize(object o)
    {
        // ...  
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string s)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Well then I will be creating seperate classes containing needed functions, for each librar right?

Comment: @Mercurial1278 - Well that really depends. Do you really expect to be switching out libraries each week or do you simply wish to make such a transition a moderate task?

Comment: I want to use Json.NET as everybody suggests now, but I know open-source projects getting abandoned every so often so in a year I may change.

Comment: I agree that this is a better solution if you just want to be safe "in case" you choose to switch to another library.  If you want to be able to swap in one JSON library or another without recompiling or test them side-by-side, the solution I proposed can do so.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys. ChaosPandion
's solution suits me the best for now.

Comment: @Mercurial1278 - Glad to be of service, best of luck on your project.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create an interface that all libraries have the capability of matching, then implementing a wrapper class for each that implements the interface using that particular library.  Each wrapper class will have to be in a separate assembly to avoid a dependency on the wrapper class's library.

Then, when you choose an implementation at runtime, you'll do it by instantiating the wrapper class through reflection.

Comment: Very much like [C# Pluggable Architecture](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/c__plugin_architecture.aspx) Liked the idea.

Comment: While this is a good solution I would suggest pursuing something a bit simpler first.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to create an interface.

Here is how we do it in Facebook C# SDK (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com)

```
public interface IJsonSerializer
{
    string SerializeObject(object obj);
    object DeserializeObject(string json, Type type);
    T DeserializeObject<T>(string json);
    object DeserializeObject(string json);
}
```

Comment: As you can't make sure that other libraries implement your interface, are you creating one class for each different library implementing this interface?

Comment: yes, we have to manually create the interface for each library. here is the example of how we do with SimpleJson http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/41e55d6506e4#Source%2fFacebook%2fJsonSerializer.cs